# I have to input HELO/EHLO commands twice before it registers on receiving server while testing SMTP

Tags: smtp, exchange-2010

We have an Exchange Server (2010) on site that sends our mail to the world using MX(DNS) records.
When I look at the queue, several domains have 421 4.4.2 Connection dropped due to ConnectionReset.
I've telnet into the SMTP port of the servers refusing connection and doing HELO or EHLO (domain) always returns Syntax error the first time it is submitted.
The second time the receiving server replies to the command.
Once I get the HELO or EHLO command to be received it takes all other commands as normal.

```
    220 smtp-gateway2.carleton.ca ESMTP Service ready
EHLO **********.ca
500 Syntax error, command unrecognized
EHLO **********.ca
250-Requested mail action okay, completed
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE 20480000
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250 OK
```

No backspaces or any other keystrokes besides what you see. I'm using our domain name that would be sending the email in the sample above.

Could this be the reason I am seeing the 4.4.2 error in our send queue? If so what would be causing this issue?

To telnet I'm using putty from our Exchange Server.

Extra information:
Web traffic for our company uses a different public IP than our Exchange server uses for mail/smtp. All information from Exchange that uses port 25 is forcefully being re-written to the correct public IP by the Firewall. There was an issue with mail having the incorrect public IP and being rejected because there is no rDNS for the web traffic IP.

Comment: I tried it a couple of times against that server and I could not reproduce that issue. I never got a syntax error and it responded properly the first EHLO. But, I was connected to that actual server, and you are not. Your connection seems to have been intercepted and diverted somewhere else.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by my connection was intercepted.

Comment: I mean I'm talking to smtp-gateway2.carleton.ca and it gives me completely different banners and responses. I think you're actually talking to some other server.

Comment: When I run a telnet session from my computer (which then uses the other public IP I get the following):
`220 smtp-gateway2.carleton.ca ESMTP Sendmail 8.15.2/8.15.2; Wed, 16 Nov 2016 15:56:26 -0500
EHLO **********.ca
500 5.5.1 Command unrecognized: {{}EHLO **********.ca"
EHLO **********.ca
    250-smtp-gateway2.carleton.ca Hello [XXX.XXX.XX.42], pleased to meet you
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-EXPN
250-VERB
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE 36700160
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-DELIVERBY
250 HELP
`

Comment: OK, that's the correct server. So now we can be sure that the problem is on your local computer or network.  You can see that some additional characters were sent before your first EHLO.

Comment: So my server is sending to the wrong server or is being intercepted by something.... Hmmm. I'll have to check what it could be. My workstation is Win10 but my server is Win2008 R2 running Exchange 2010. The firewall is re-writing the packet IPs so they look to be coming from the Exchange server when being sent by the Exchange server.

I know this is odd but we had an issue with the wrong public IP was being used on mail. In the comment above, when I telnet from my workstation it says Hello (public IP of web traffic).

Comment: Yeah, you have two distinct issues: First, the connection shown in your original post didn't actually go to the server you think it did, and second, your client is sending garbage when it opens the connection. You need to set PuTTY to raw mode instead of telnet mode when using it for something like this.

Comment: PuTTY in raw from my workstation did work on 1st go and I learned something new. I guess I found out why some sites are just flaking on our server... 

Not sure I know how to figure out which server the session is going to. I tried to connect into our own server and only when used it's internal IP did I get the correct banner. It's hostname and public IP give that weird banner like in my first example. So either the firewall or some ?sophisticated server in the middle??

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is the active telnet mode that is standard in puTTY
I had the same problem with puTTY then I changed the configuration under telnet from active to passive and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In your PuTTY Configuration for the connection to your Exchange Server, go to `Category > Connection > Telnet`, then change the `Telnet negotiation mode` from `Active` to `Passive`.

[image: PuTTY Passive Negotiation]

[ref: PuTTY Documentation Help](https://documentation.help/PuTTY/config-ptelnet.html)

**4.16.2 Passive and active Telnet negotiation modes**

In a Telnet connection, there are two types of data passed between the client and the server: actual text, and negotiations about which Telnet extra features to use.

PuTTY can use two different strategies for negotiation:

In active mode, PuTTY starts to send negotiations as soon as the connection is opened.
In passive mode, PuTTY will wait to negotiate until it sees a negotiation from the server.
The obvious disadvantage of passive mode is that if the server is also operating in a passive mode, then negotiation will never begin at all. For this reason PuTTY defaults to active mode.

However, sometimes passive mode is required in order to successfully get through certain types of firewall and Telnet proxy server. If you have confusing trouble with a firewall, you could try enabling passive mode to see if it helps.

Comment: This answer was already given by someone else. Be aware that when you are just adding details, you are also allowed to edit existing answers.